# Terraform with vSphere: the operation is not supported on the object (resource pool)

Tags: terraform, vsphere

I have a Terraform file to create a resource pool on my home vSphere instance. The Terraform file looks as follows:

```
provider "vsphere" {
  vsphere_server       = "${var.vsphere_server}"
  user                 = "${var.vsphere_user}"
  password             = "${var.vsphere_password}"
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = "Datacenter1"
}

data "vsphere_compute_cluster" "compute_cluster" {
  name          = "Cluster1"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

resource "vsphere_resource_pool" "resource_pool" {
  name                    = "terraform-resource-pool-test"
  parent_resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_compute_cluster.compute_cluster.resource_pool_id}"
}
```

The output from terraform plan is the following:

```
# vsphere_resource_pool.resource_pool will be created
  + resource "vsphere_resource_pool" "resource_pool" {
      + cpu_expandable          = true
      + cpu_limit               = -1
      + cpu_reservation         = 0
      + cpu_share_level         = "normal"
      + cpu_shares              = (known after apply)
      + id                      = (known after apply)
      + memory_expandable       = true
      + memory_limit            = -1
      + memory_reservation      = 0
      + memory_share_level      = "normal"
      + memory_shares           = (known after apply)
      + name                    = "terraform-resource-pool-test"
      + parent_resource_pool_id = "resgroup-8"
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

But I always get back the following error:

> vsphere_resource_pool.resource_pool: Creating...
>
> Error: ServerFaultCode: The operation is not supported on the object.
>
> on main.tf line 34, in resource "vsphere_resource_pool"
>   "resource_pool":   34: resource "vsphere_resource_pool"
>   "resource_pool" {

Any idea on how to solve this? I'm using vSphere Version 6.0.0 Build 3617395

Comment: I have the same error on TERRAFORM_VERSION=0.11.14. Vsphere version: 6.7.

Is there any update?

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine.

Some manual fix will be helpful for this case.

#### Since it is your own system, it should be fine to clean the tfstate files, otherwise, backup them first.

1. clean the environment

```
# clean below folder and files from current directory, where you run `terraform apply`

rm -rf .terraform
rm terraform.tfstate* in any subfolders 

# clean below folder from home directory.
rm ~/.terraform.d/
```

2. deploy again.

```
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply
```

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion did not work. I run into the same error. I believe it has to do with a specific version of vSphere. Also in the UI, I can't seem to find the option to create resource pools so maybe it's not supported in the specific vSphere version I have installed and hence TF can also not perform the action. Not sure about it though...

Comment: I have the same error on TERRAFORM_VERSION=0.11.14. Vsphere version: 6.7. Is there any update?